# Multiplying adjacent elements and compare which has a higher value

Tags: java, arrays, compare, multiplication, negative-number

I am trying to compare which has a greater quotient when multiplying adjacent elements:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] inputArray = {-5, 8, -9, 1, -5, 4};
    int x = 0;
    long maxsofar = 0;
    while (x < inputArray.length - 1) {
        int currentmax = inputArray[x] * inputArray[x + 1];
        maxsofar = (maxsofar > currentmax) ? maxsofar : currentmax;
        }
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println(maxsofar);
}
```

So far my code works, but when I try to use negative integers on my array, it just outputs 0.

Comment: change `long maxsofar = 0` with `long maxofar = Long.MIN_VALUE;`

Comment: just to short your code instead of if(maxsofar>currentmax)::::::::::::::::::: use if(maxsofar<currentmax)maxsofar=currentmax;  ///////////////////////////////// and then no need of else...     :)

Comment: Or if he already knows the numbers in advance he can calculate that on a sheet of paper and make it even shorter : maxsofar=0!

Comment: can you tell what is the expected result

Comment: OMG i did not see that.. thanks soo much guys.. i  didn't realize that i initialized my maxsofar to 0.

Comment: What, in the context of `Multiplying adjacent elements` is `a greater quotient` / `a higher value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because 0 is > than negative numbers. All your adjacent elements when multiplied create negative numbers->

-5*8=-40

8*-9=-72

etc.

So 0 is the maximum one.

You can use Math.abs() for example to use the absolute value. Or you can set maxsofar to the Long.MIN_VALUE to get the largest number even if negative. The way you have done it you get the largest number > 0.

And also this way your program works for exactly that array (having 5 elemtents). A nicer way would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 2; i++) {
            int currentmax = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1];
            if (maxsofar < currentmax) {                
                maxsofar = currentmax;
            } //No need to handle the case where you say A=A :)
        }
```

Or even better you can do `Math.max(maxsofar,currentmax)`;

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
long maxsofar = Long.MIN_VALUE;
```

as initialization. Then the next max is guaranteed to be larger.

Comment: This creates an error cannot find symbol.  The constant is Long.MIN_VALUE.